# What is the Django equivilent to Rolify for rails

Tags: python, django, roles, rolify

I have a Django app with an API that I built. I have been looking at Rolify for roles to give users permission through role and was wondering if there was anything similar that is available for Python/Django?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe django-user-roles module can work for you:

https://github.com/dabapps/django-user-roles